# How to specify utf-8 code in QString literals?

Tags: qt, unicode, utf-8, qt5, qstring

```
QString s="hello";
s.replace("\0xc2\0xa0","&nbsp;");
qDebug()<<s;
```

In the above code, I want to replace possible non-break spaces(0xc2a0) to `"&nbsp;"`, but the output is

```
"&nbsp;h&nbsp;e&nbsp;l&nbsp;l&nbsp;o&nbsp;"
```

, why? It would be better not to use another function to convert the literal to UFT-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include "MainWin.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QPlainTextEdit>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QPlainTextEdit edit;

    // "hello world" string from UTF-8 hexadecimal representation

    // UTF-8, normal space (0x20)
    QString hello_world_normal("\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x20\x77\x6f\x72\x6c\x64");

    qDebug() << hello_world_normal;
    edit.appendPlainText(hello_world_normal);

    // UTF-8, non-breaking space (0xC2 0xA0)
    QString hello_world_non_breaking("\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\xc2\xa0\x77\x6f\x72\x6c\x64");

    qDebug() << hello_world_non_breaking;
    edit.appendPlainText(hello_world_non_breaking);

    hello_world_non_breaking.replace(QString("\xc2\xa0"), "&nbsp;");

    qDebug() << hello_world_non_breaking;
    edit.appendPlainText(hello_world_non_breaking);

    edit.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: It works! I don't know why I added 0 before x, must be confused with something else. Thank you!